# json - add 2 elements on the same node at once ? (or in an inexistent node)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

This must be easy..but I can't find the answer...

```
    var crit = {
        'webshopId': webshopId,
        'type': 'product'} 
    };
```

i need to add sku.regularPrice = { $gte : parameters.minPrice} on crit;

so...if I do

```
crit.sku.regularPrice = { $gte : parameters.minPrice};
```

I will receive a exception: TypeError: Cannot set property 'regularPrice' of undefined

it's because sku does not exists on crit.

Ok, so, let's create...

```
crit.sku = {};
```

This will bring me un unwished result...like this...

```
 { webshopId: 'rawDemo',
   type: 'product',
   sku: { regularPrice: { '$gte': '3' } } }
```

So, a child node has been created :( I really need : sku.regularPrice : { $gte : 3}

So, my expected result must be...

```
 { webshopId: 'rawDemo',
   type: 'product',
   sku.regularPrice: { '$gte': '3' } }
```

at the crit variable. A hard coded representation could be...

```
 var crit = { webshopId: 'rawDemo',
   type: 'product',
   sku.regularPrice: { '$gte': '3' } }
```

any clue ?

Comment: Just to clarify, you need the attribute name to literally include a . in it?

Comment: My bad, sorry...I just edited the question for a better understanding. Basically I need to add a atribute.subAttribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can't use dot notation to access the variable you want. You need:

```
var crit = {
    'webshopId': webshopId,
    'type': 'product'} 
};

crit['sku.regularPrice'] = { $gte : parameters.minPrice};
```

Which would result in:

```
{ 
   webshopId: 'rawDemo',
   type: 'product',
   'sku.regularPrice': { '$gte': '3' }
}
```

Comment: Awesome !!! tyvm !!! and I think I learned a new thing today. thaks for the opportunity !